# Observable angular no emite cambios a los subs

Tags: angular, observable

Tengo un servicio sencillo en el que actualizo los datos desde un componente A y los leo en un componente B, la actualización de los datos se realiza correctamente desde el componente A pero el B no recibe los cambios

Código del servicio

```
private _vacations : Vacation[]
private _vacations$ : BehaviorSubject<Vacation[]>
constructor() { 
  this._vacations = []
  this._vacations$ = new BehaviorSubject<Vacation[]>([{date:'',document:'',names:'', position:''}])
}

get vacations$() : Observable<Vacation[]>{
  return this._vacations$.asObservable()
}
set addVacation (newVacation : Vacation){
  this._vacations.push(newVacation)
  this._vacations$.next(this._vacations)       
}
```

Código del componente A al insertar datos (con un log en el servicio se observa que si inserta)

```
constructor ( private  vacationsService: VacationService) {}
gestionar (){
    let vacation : Vacation = {   
      date: this.initialDate.value,
      document: this.employed.value.document,
      names: this.employed.value.names + this.employed.value.surnames,
      position: this.employed.value.position
    }   
    this.vacationsService.addVacation = vacation
  }
```

Código del componente B (aqui no se actualizan los datos cuando se insertan desde el A )

```
  items : Vacation[] = []
  
  constructor ( private vacationsService: VacationService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.vacationsService.vacations$.subscribe((data: Vacation[]) => {    
      this.items= data
      console.log(data);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu service `addVacation` es una función y la estas usando como una propiedad

```
this.vacationsService.addVacation = vacation // Error

this.vacationsService.addVacation(vacation) // correcto
```

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que tu servicio no este compartiendo la misma instancia para los 2 componentes. En Angular, los servicios suelen ser objetos singleton, lo que significa que se instancian solo una vez por aplicación y se comparten entre componentes, directivas y otros servicios que los inyectan. Sin embargo, hay escenarios en los que los servicios de Angular no comparten la misma instancia:

¿Estas usando en tu servicio el decorador @Injectable()?

```
@Injectable()
export class VacationService {
    private _vacations : Vacation[]
    private _vacations$ : BehaviorSubject<Vacation[]>
    constructor() { 
      this._vacations = []
      this._vacations$ = new BehaviorSubject<Vacation[]>([{date:'',document:'',names:'', position:''}])
    }
    
    get vacations$() : Observable<Vacation[]>{
      return this._vacations$.asObservable()
    }
    set addVacation (newVacation : Vacation){
      this._vacations.push(newVacation)
      this._vacations$.next(this._vacations)       
    }
}
```

Si estas usando modules, estas importando correctamente como provider el servicio?

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,
   RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes,
      ) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent,SiblingComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers : [VacationService] // <-- Tu servicio
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

El error estaba en algo que omití mensionar, y es que el componente A (el que inserta info) era hijo del componente B (el que imprime) y estaba importando como provider el servicio, no sé porqué pero generaba el error.

- se eliminó el servicio de la matriz de providers del componente hijo
- se eliminó el servicio de la matriz de providers del elemento padre (aunque en este no ocurre el error)